# Disable automatic join of nested outline groups - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having issues with adjacent and nested outline groups and Excel combining them together.

What happens:

1. Group columns A:F together

   - This works fine.
   - Group is created with the expand/collapse icons
2. Group columns A:C together

   - This works fine.
   - A nested group is created inside the one done in step 1.
3. Group columns E:F together

   - This does not work. No expand/collapse icons are available, only dots marking it is grouped deeper. (see picture below)
   - Excel decides I want to join this somehow to the first one.
4. Group columns G:J together

   - This creates a group but combines it with the one done in step 1
   - Can this behavior be avoided?

**Nested outline groups**

[image: IMG:]

This behaviour happens always at one of the edges of outline groups. The side depends on which option you have enabled in outline settings. I used "Summary columns to right of detail" enabled.

Is there a way to have nested groups work properly at the edges without combining them in? And is there a way to have adjacent outline groups without gap rows/columns in between without hiding rows/columns?

EDIT 2020-06-16

As @Owen pointed out, my intention with this seems to be unclear. My sheet has multiple different column groups and these groups some have subgroups in them. I would like to be able to show and hide these groups and subgroups easily while inputting data to the rows. Hiding is needed because there are a lot of columns used and only one or two groups worked on at the same time.

Outline is an easy way to achieve fast showing and hiding of columns. Using regular hide makes it difficult and end users of this file will not be able figure out that there are hidden columns without the clear indication of an outline.

Adding a summary column after each group will solve the problem, but the summary column does not provide anything in my case expect solve the outline issue. No summary is needed for column groups.

[Groups of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNOo1.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Could you edit your post and include a screenshot of your data or some dummy data that represents what you're trying to do? I think there are definitely limitations to Outline in Excel, but there may be a way to overcome them depending on your data.

Comment: @Owen Hi, there was the image as a link and someone suggested a edit to include it as embedded. The contents of the columns do not matter for the outline it always combines regardless of what is in the cells. Grouping location and summary column position define that.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My point is that depending on your specific use, you may find it's better to avoid using Outline altogether. It's tricky to recommend a workaround without understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Outline/Group functionality is, as far as I can tell, to allow you to quickly show or hide the detail that contributes to a summary row or column.

[Outline (group) data in a Worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff)

You want to have two groups which end on the same column. In the context of the purpose stated above, this doesn't make sense - because it would imply that the two differently-sized collections of columns are represented by the same summary column.

Nevertheless, I replicated your issue in O365 - groups *ending* in the same row or column will not get their own "grouping line" across the row header or column header, they will be subsumed into the longer group already present, if there is one. These new groups *do* get a number in the list of 1,2,3,etc in the headers area, though this may be confusing with lots of numbers.

Generally if you are using this feature to show aggregates, a pivot table is a more scalable and predictable method (Outline is limited to 8 groups). Failing that, simply creating a summary table that shows just the aggregated then perhaps using Split to keep the summary in the top left of the user's screen would be enough.

If you're not using it to show aggregates, but as a way of hiding columns for some other reason, then you may want to consider re-organizing your columns.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation how those work. I tried to make my target clearer with an edit to the original post.